# Compare Key : Value in JSON object 1 to Key : Value in JSON object 2 and if condition matches, alter the Value

Tags: php, json

I have 2 JSON objects, one for Male Genetics and one for Female Genetics. These are shown below:

Male:

```
$male='{ 
    "Bell-Albino":"Bb",
    "Rainwater-Albino":"null",
    "Tremper-Albino":"null",
    "Murphys-Patternless":"null",
    "Eclipse":"Ee",
    "Marble-Eye":"null",
    "Blizzard":"Zz",
    "Mack-Snow":"Mm",
    "Super-Snow":"null",
    "Gem-Snow":"null",
    "TUG-Snow":"null",
    "Line-Bred-Snow":"null",
    "Enigma":"null",
    "White-and-Yellow":"null",
    "Wildtype":"null",
    "Giant":"null" 
}';
```

Female:

```
$female='{ 
    "Bell-Albino":"BB",
    "Rainwater-Albino":"null",
    "Tremper-Albino":"null",
    "Murphys-Patternless":"null",
    "Eclipse":"null",
    "Marble-Eye":"null",
    "Blizzard":"zz",
    "Mack-Snow":"mm",
    "Super-Snow":"null",
    "Gem-Snow":"null",
    "TUG-Snow":"null",
    "Line-Bred-Snow":"null",
    "Enigma":"null",
    "White-and-Yellow":"null",
    "Wildtype":"null",
    "Giant":"null" 
}';
```

If we take the `Eclipse` `key` from the `Male` object, we have `"Eclipse":"Ee"` and if we do the same for the `Female` object we have `"Eclipse":"null"`.

In the genetics I use `EE` to signify dominant, `Ee` to signify recessive and `ee` to signify null but can be used in gene calculation.

What I need to do on the fly, is check the `keys` for the 2 objects and if one object has a `key` (`Eclipse` for example) that has a value that is *not* `"null"` (which means it could be `EE or Ee`) it needs to check the other object and replace the `null` value in the other object with lowercase letters like `ee`.

I know of array intersect (when using arrays) but I'm not even sure that would be the right thing to use anyway?

This is quite difficult for me to explain, and code, so apologies for waffling a bit. If I need to clarify anything please say so.

Comment: Please don't sign your posts with your name. Signatures, salutations and taglines do not belong in your Stack Overflow posts.

Comment: Alrighty will remember that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//convert to arrays
$male = json_decode($male, true);
$female = json_decode($female, true);

foreach( $male as $key => $value ) {
  if ( $value != 'null' && $female[$key] == 'null' ) {
      $female[$key] = strtolower($value);
  } else {
    if ($female[$key] != 'null' && $value == 'null')
      $male[$key] = strtolower($female[$key]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Reading it this looks like it's the right direction, but when I try it, i get `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Comment: I just adjusted it, the `true` option was missing

Answer (score 1):

One other option. If a value is `'null'`, you can just overwrite it with the lowercase value of the other gender without checking what it is. If the other value is `'null'` as well, nothing changes, and if it isn't you get the lowercase version of whatever it is.

```
$genders = array_map('json_decode', [$male, $female]);

foreach ($genders as $gender => $values) {
    foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
        // overwrite all nulls with lowercase corresponding value of other gender
        if ($value == 'null') $genders[$gender]->$key = strtolower($genders[!$gender]->$key);
    }
}

list($male, $female) = $genders;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$male = json_decode($male);
$female = json_decode($female);

foreach($male as $key => $value){
    if(array_key_exists($key, $female)){
        if($value === "null"){
            $male->{$key} = $female->{$key};
        }
    }
}

foreach($female as $key => $value){
    if(array_key_exists($key, $male)){
        if($value === "null"){
            $female->{$key} = $male->{$key};
        }
    }
}

print_r($male);
print_r($female);

// convert back to json if you need to?
$male = json_encode($male);
$female = json_encode($female);
```

Answer (score -1):

Let me know if this fits the bill:

```
for(i in $male){
  if ($male[i] != 'null' && $female[i] == 'null'){
    $female[i] = 'ee';
  }
}

for(i in $female){
  if ($female[i] != 'null' && $male[i] == 'null'){
    $male[i] = 'ee';
  }
}
```

You can test it here:

https://jsfiddle.net/tz746xdz/1/

... and a PHP version:

```
$maleDecode = json_decode($male);
$femaleDecode = json_decode($female);
foreach ($maleDecode as $key=>$val){
  if ($maleDecode->$key != 'null' and $femaleDecode->$key == 'null')
    $femaleDecode->$key = 'ee';
}
foreach ($femaleDecode as $key=>$val){
  if ($femaleDecode->$key != 'null' and $maleDecode->$key == 'null')
    $maleDecode->$key = 'ee';
}
```

Comment: Is this for JS or PHP?